# IEnumerable.contains not finding a matching item in the Collection, which does exist

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have an `IEnumerable<MyClass>` returned from a foo method. `MyClass` contains a nested class and typically looks like below. The issue is `Assert` always returns false.

```
MyClass
{
    SomeNestedClass
    {
        public decimal  decimalField1;
        public int      intField2;
    }
}
```

I am writing a Unit test to test the `Foo` method by

```
// Arrange
var expectedItem = new MyClass 
{
    new SomeNestedClass
    {
        decimalField1 = 10M,
        intField2 = 20
    }
}

// Act
var results = sut.Foo();

// Assert
Assert.IsTrue(results.Contains(expectedItem));
```

**The problem is Assert is always false.**

Comment: probably not comparing the same object. you can use FirstOrDefault(x=>x.decimalField == expectemItem.decimalField && x.intField2 == expectedItem.inteField2)

Comment: Reference equality is the default.  Just because two things look the same *to you* doesn't mean that .NET considers them equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Contains` will use the default equality comparer for the type when trying to find a match, which is a reference comparison for reference types like classes. Since we know that there is no reference to the object you just created in the list, this will not work.

One simple way around this is to use the `System.Linq` method `Any()`, which returns true if any items in an `IEnumerable` meet the specified conditions.

For example:

```
Assert.IsTrue(results.Any(result => 
    result.decimalField1 == expectedItem.decimalField1 &&
    result.intField2 == expectedItem.intField2));
```

---

A slightly more laborious but re-usable way to do this is to write a `SomeNestedClass` comparer that can be passed to the `Contains` method (I'm using `SomeNestedClass` even though `result` was declared as a `MyClass` in the example because that's the only class that has fields we can use for comparison):

```
public class SomeNestedClassComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyClass.SomeNestedClass>
{
    public bool Equals(MyClass.SomeNestedClass x, MyClass.SomeNestedClass y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return ReferenceEquals(x, y);
        return x.decimalField1 == y.decimalField1 && x.intField2 == y.intField2;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyClass.SomeNestedClass obj)
    {
        return obj.decimalField1.GetHashCode() * 17 + 
               obj.intField2.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And now we tell `Contains` to use this class when trying to find a match for our `expectedItem`:

```
Assert.IsTrue(results.Contains(expectedItem, new SomeNestedClassComparer()));
```

Answer (score 3):

We do not have enough info there (implementation of sut.Foo();) but I suspect you have to override the Object.Equals() method in the MyClass type.
Without that, the Contains() funtion will only check against the references equality.